# How does Google use "Google" as a source address in text messages

Tags: sms, smpp

I've seen other companies do this, but Google is a notable example.

When you turn on two-factor authentication with Google, one of the options is to receive an SMS when you logon. I've noticed that the sender's address, rather than being an MSISDN like 346-555-1234 is "Google".

How are they doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the smpp 3.4 specifications, the source address can be defined as an alphanumeric string of 11 characters

Comment: Just to extend this, it relates as well to the Type Of Number setting for the source address, which has to be 5 for alphanumeric addresses.